# Access Popup Form Not Displaying Textbox

Tags: ms-access, popup, vba

I'm running Access 2016.  Using VBA I have a popup form which displays just before initiating a lengthy copy operation.  Once the copy completes, I close the popup.  The problem is that popup only displays the form's caption and not the contents of the form (which is a yellow background with a label containing "Backup in progress").  The form displays properly if I manually open it.  I can't figure out what's going wrong.  Here's the code that executes:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmBackupInProgress"
fso.CopyFile strOldPath, strNewPath
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmBackupInProgress"
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

-- Geoff

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to add a "DoEvents" command before the CopyFile to get it to display.